# Plot a transient analysis over frequency steps [LTSpice / Simetrix]

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice, simulation

I am looking for a way to plot the end value of a transient analysis (let's say the output voltages of a SMPS after 3 ms) over a parameter (in this case frequency from 10 kHz to 250 kHz in 10 kHz steps).
This parameter defines other parameters for two voltage sources that then controls the turn off/on times of two switching MOSFETs.

Any idea how I can realize this?
A transient analysis with multistep (params) gives me the x-axis in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you have is a `.step` and you're measuring the same quantity (e.g. `V(out)`) then you can use `.meas` to measure the value of interest at that particular time, then plot the stepped data:

[image: test]

Here `{C}` is parameterized and used with a `.step` command. The `.meas` command measures `V(o)` when the `time` is 9 ms. Then the error log can be opened up (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> with the schematic window active), <kbd>RClick</kbd> and choose *Plot .step'ed .meas data*. You'll get a plot like that small window.

Comment: THIS IS GOLD!

Thank you so much!